# Mongoose Populate Returns Some Empty Objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 1 main collection and 1 collection with a ref to the main one. Code looks like :

```
// Ref schema
    const onlineSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        _id: {
            type: Number,
            ref: 'Player',
            unique: true
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: true
    });

//main schema

const playerSchema = mongoose.Schema({

_id: { // User ID
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    default: 0
},
firstname: {
    type: String
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
lastname: {
    type: String
},
barfoo: {
   type: Boolean
}
...

})
```

I populate it with this code :

```
var baz = bar;
...
        Online.find().populate({
            path: '_id',
            match: {
                [ baz + 'foo']: true
            }
        }).exec(function(err, online) {
            if (err) {
                winston.error(err);
            } else {
                winston.error(util.inspect(online, {
                    showHidden: false,
                    depth: null
                }));

            }
        });
```

If there are 10 elements in online and only 7 match `[ baz + 'foo']: true` I get 7 proper arrays and 3 empty arrays that look like this:

```
    { updatedAt: 2016-12-23T18:00:32.725Z,
createdAt: 2016-12-23T18:00:32.725Z,
_id: null,
 __v: 0 },
```

Why is this happening and how to I filter the final result so it only shows the matching elements?

I can use filter to remove the null arrays after I get the result but I'd like to know how to prevent the the query from passing null arrays in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening ?

This is happening because you get all the documents with `Online.find()` but the `player` will be populated only for records that match your condition. Your `match` is for the `populate`, not for the `find()` query.

> How do I filter the final result so it only shows the matching
>   elements ?

You cant find a nested elements of a referenced collections since there is  no join in MongoDB. But you can :

- keep your schema and use aggregation with `$lookup` :

  ```
  Online.aggregate(
      [{
          $lookup: {
              from: "players",
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "players"
          }
      }, {
          $unwind: "$players"
      }, {
          $match: {
              'players.barfoo': true
          }
      }],
      function(err, result) {
          console.log(result);
      });
  ```
- change your schema to include `Player` as a subdocument :

  ```
  const playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      //...
  });

  const onlineSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      player: playerSchema
  }, {
      timestamps: true
  });

  var Online = mongoose.model('Online', onlineSchema);

  Online.find({'player.barfoo':true}).exec(function(err, online) {
      console.log(online);
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Dont make `_id` the `reference` of another schema, instead make another `field` name `player` and give `reference` through that.

```
const onlineSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    player: {
        type: Number,
        ref: 'Player',
        unique: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Population:

```
Online.find().populate({
    path: 'player',
    match: {
        [ baz + 'foo']: true
    }
}).exec(...);
```

Comment: Populate would not work properly until I used _id as the reference.

Answer (score 0):

dont use _id to ref field.. because its default filed in mongoDB to create index unique.. change you're field name